# non-repeatable @NamedQuery

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to define serveral named queries like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
@NamedQuery(query = "SELECT i FROM TableA i WHERE i.Id = :Id", name = "findAById")
@NamedQuery(query = "SELECT i FROM TableA i WHERE i.name = :name", name = "findAByName")
public class TableA  
{   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="Name")
    String name = "";

\\... more code


}
```

But doing so, I get the following error message in eclipse:

> Duplicate annotation of non-repeatable type @NamedQuery. Only
>   annotation types marked @Repeatable can be used multiple times at one
>   target.

and at compilation:

> java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for
>   class: interface javax.persistence.NamedQuery:
>   @javax.persistence.NamedQuery(lockMode=NONE, hints=[], query=SELECT i
>   FROM TableA i WHERE i.name = :name,
>   name=findAByName)     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown
>   Source)

For me this limitation of only one named Query per class makes not much sense. Is this a bug or a feature? Are there workarounds to define more Named Queries per class?

Comment: it's a bit old question but might help someone else, with JPA 2.2 is possible now, there is no need to use  NamedQueries as a container annoation for multiple NamedQuery, you can just go with the code above that you have and compiler won't give you any error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey you need to define as following:

```
@NamedQueries({
     @NamedQuery(query = "SELECT i FROM TableA i WHERE i.Id = :Id", name = "findAById"),
     @NamedQuery(query = "SELECT i FROM TableA i WHERE i.name = :name", name = "findAByName")
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Works well!

Answer (score -1):

Use the following:-

```
@NamedQueries( 
  value={
     @NamedQuery(name = "findAById", query = "SELECT i FROM TableA i WHERE i.Id = :Id"),
     @NamedQuery(name = "findAByName", query = "SELECT i FROM TableA i WHERE i.name = :name")
  }
)
```

Comment: This is a copy of the already existing answer, with irrelevant changes.